# Open and decode

Tags: input, strings, ifthenelse

I use `\pato{R}{2015}{07}{27}{A}{1}{4}{black}`
to `\input` my `sub-archive R20150727A1-4.tex`, and it works for me.

How can I perform a new command, say `\otap{R20150727A1-4}`,
that decode and assign for example:

```
R--> first variable;  
2015 --> second variable;
```

and so on?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

This may not be elegant, but it works:

```
\def\scanonetonine#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8#9{%
    \def\myletter{#1}%
    \def\myyear{#2#3#4#5}%
    \def\mymonth{#6#7}%
    \def\myday{#8#9}%
    \scanrest
}
\def\scanrest#1#2#3#4{%
    \def\myrest{#1#2#3#4}%
}
\def\otap#1{{%
    \scanonetonine#1%
    % now we can do anything with \my*, but let's just print them here
    (\myletter)(\myyear)(\mymonth)(\myday)(\myrest)%
}}
```

With these definitions, `\otap{R20150727A1-4}` produces `(R)(2015)(07)(27)(A1-4)` in the output. Due to the group in the final command, these macros disappear when the expansion of `\otap` is finished.

The `%` signs at the ends-of-lines are all necessary to avoid producing unwanted whitespace.

Comment: Thank you @wrtprnft. 

A second related question:  

How about passing `\mymonth` as an integer inside a `\ifthenelse` or `\ifcase` command?

Becuase `\mymonth` in a line outside `\otap` produces nothing,  
just like my approach 
`\StrMid{R20150727A1-4}{6}{7}`  
from xstring package

Comment: @JOM: I just tried `\ifnum\myyear<2016 old\else new\fi` and `\ifthenelse{\myyear<2016}{old}{new}` and they both work inside the \otap declaration. If you want to use them after \otap, you have to replace the double braces `{{` and `}}` by single ones (the other ones delimit the argument to \def, the inner ones form a TeX group).